# Sign in is not working after confirmable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am using devise gem,when i click the link from email **Confirm my account** after confirmable from email.

My sign in page is not working.

Comment: What is the error displayed in logs? Also add your code snippets and devise config file, half filled questions like this are closed

Comment: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 6ms @Bijendra

Answer (score 0):

Put this:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
```

In development.rb file?